# 'mysqld' using a lot of ram in Ubuntu 16.04, is it normal?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, memory-usage, django

I am working on my Django project and recently installed mysql-server on my ubuntu 16.04. It is using a lot of ram approx 800 MB to 1GB, is it normal?

Picture attached :[image]

Comment: If you have a large database, yes.

Comment: No! I don't have large database,.I just installed it!

Comment: I guess this is related https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1572801?comments=all not sure if is a mysql problem

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not normal.  It is caused by the bug [Excessive memory used in memory/innodb/os0file starting 5.7.8](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80772).

It is tracked in Ubuntu as [Excessive consumption RAM of mysqld daemon in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/akonadi/+bug/1576930), and there is also [a discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/4gnj93/mysql_5712_ubuntu_1604_ridiculous_memory/).